Pandas: Merging two dataFrames with repeated values in the merging column
I would like to merge two DataFrames that contain repeated records in the merging column. Here's an example:
Sample DataFrames:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Sample data for df1 and df2
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
                    'tr1': [10, 80, 50, 40, 60, 20, 70, 90, 30]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                    'tr2': [15, 45, 55, 35, 95, 75, 65]})

df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

This produces the following result:
df
    id   tr1   tr2
    1   10  15.0
    1   10  45.0
    1   10  55.0
    2   80  35.0
    2   80  95.0
    2   50  35.0
    2   50  95.0
    2   40  35.0
    2   40  95.0
    3   60  75.0
    3   60  65.0
    3   20  75.0
    3   20  65.0
    3   70  75.0
    3   70  65.0
    3   90  75.0
    3   90  65.0
    4   30   NaN

However, this isn't quite correct. For instance, id = 1 should not have repeated values of tr1 as 10 for each of the tr2 values. To address this, I thought of adding record numbers to differentiate the rows and then discarding these numbers after merging:
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4],
                    'tr1': [10, 80, 50, 40, 60, 20, 70, 90, 30],
                    'n1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                    'tr2': [15, 45, 55, 35, 95, 75, 65],
                    'n2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})

df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

# Remove duplicates based on record numbers
df['tr1'] = np.where(df.duplicated('n1', keep='first'), np.nan, df['tr1'])
df['tr2'] = np.where(df.duplicated('n2', keep='first'), np.nan, df['tr2'])
df = df[['id', 'tr1', 'tr2']]

# Drop rows where both 'tr1' and 'tr2' are NaN
df = df.dropna(subset=['tr1', 'tr2'], how='all')

This results in:
id   tr1   tr2
    1  10.0  15.0
    1   NaN  45.0
    1   NaN  55.0
    2  80.0  35.0
    2   NaN  95.0
    2  50.0   NaN
    2  40.0   NaN
    3  60.0  75.0
    3   NaN  65.0
    3  20.0   NaN
    3  70.0   NaN
    3  90.0   NaN
    4  30.0   NaN

This is an improvement, but still not exactly what I want. For example, id = 2 should not have NaN for tr1 in the second row. It should be:
2  80.0  35.0
2  50.0  95.0
2  40.0   NaN

And for id 3 for example:
3  60.0  75.0
3  20.0  65.0
3  70.0   NaN
3  90.0   NaN

The expected output should look like this:
Desired Output:
id  tr1 tr2
1   10  15
1   nan 45
1   nan 55
2   80  35
2   50  95
2   40  nan
3   60  75
3   20  65
3   70  nan
3   90  nan
4   30  nan

Any idea how I can reach it?

Code
When use merge, attach the result of cumcount to on(left & right)
out = df1.merge(
    df2, 
    left_on=['id', df1.groupby('id').cumcount()], 
    right_on=['id', df2.groupby('id').cumcount()], 
    how='outer'
)

out[['id', 'tr1', 'tr2']]:
    id   tr1   tr2
0    1  10.0  15.0
1    1   NaN  45.0
2    1   NaN  55.0
3    2  80.0  35.0
4    2  50.0  95.0
5    2  40.0   NaN
6    3  60.0  75.0
7    3  20.0  65.0
8    3  70.0   NaN
9    3  90.0   NaN
10   4  30.0   NaN


You can solve this issue by adding a cumulative count to both DataFrames to identify each repeated value in the merging column uniquely. Then, merge the DataFrames on both the merging column and the cumulative count.
import pandas as pd

def merge_with_repeated_values(df1, df2, merge_column):
    """
    Merge DataFrames with repeated values using cumulative count.
    
    Args:
        df1, df2 (pd.DataFrame): DataFrames to merge.
        merge_column (str): Column to merge on.
    
    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: Merged DataFrame with all aligned rows.
    """
    # Add cumulative count to handle repeated values
    temp_count_col = '__temp_count__'
    df1[temp_count_col] = df1.groupby(merge_column).cumcount()
    df2[temp_count_col] = df2.groupby(merge_column).cumcount()
    
    # Merge on both original column and count
    merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=[merge_column, temp_count_col], how='outer')
    
    # Drop the temporary count column
    return merged_df.drop(columns=[temp_count_col])

